# Where can I get the C VERSION of go-lang source code?

Tags: go

As I know, go-lang is **written by C at the beginning**, and now it is written by itself. I want to figure out some fundamental implementations of go-lang, such as multi-return-value-of-function, which probably use structure I guess.

But now the go-lang version of go-lang source code has conceal these details, so where can I get the **C version of go-lang source code (history version)**? I've checked golang.org, nothing found.

Thanks.

Comment: [This is the oldest tag that appears in their git repo](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/weekly.2009-11-06)

Comment: What about searching [here](https://github.com/golang/go/search?l=c)?

Comment: The old compilers didn't translate Go programs to C, so the old versions won't necessarily help you answer that question any better than the new ones.  In both cases you have a program that converts Go source code to object files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [Go 1.5 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5)
>
> The compiler and runtime are now written entirely in Go (with a little
>   assembler). C is no longer involved in the implementation, and so the
>   C compiler that was once necessary for building the distribution is
>   gone.

Therefore, check out the [source code](https://go.googlesource.com/go) for previous release: `release-branch.go1.4`.

For example,

```
git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go --branch release-branch.go1.4 --single-branch go1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

> [The r56 release was the first stable release](https://golang.org/doc/devel/pre_go1.html) and corresponds to weekly.2011-03-07.1.

[The code is on github](https://github.com/golang/go/releases/tag/release.r56). It includes `C`, `bash`, `go`.

Answer (score 0):

I use Go 1.4.2 to bootstrap newer Go versions. I did a Go 1.6 build just this week.

It looks like there is a Go 1.4.3 available here: https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.3.src.tar.gz